# Hibernate 5 to hibernate 6.2

Tags: hibernate-envers, hibernate-6.x

I m currently migrate from hibernate 5 to 6

I'm using envers with my custom revision table that contain a field RevisionType like this

```
class MyCustomRevision {
  ...
  ...
  RevisionType revisionType;
}
```

when i save en entity, i have 0/1 or 2 in my BDD.

after the migration hibernate say :

```
class org.hibernate.envers.RevisionType cannot be cast to class java.lang.Byte (org.hibernate.envers.RevisionType is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader
```

I have activate log `org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind` to TRACE and i can see that hibernate try to bind my revision_type with `ADD`,`MOD` or `DEL` and not the ordinal value.

```
[TRACE] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [10] as [TINYINT] - [ADD]
```

I have try to force the column definition with

```
@Enumerated
@Column(columnDefinition = "smallint")
RevisionType revisionType;
```

but same error, and i have about 700 entities so i would like to have the same behavior as before

Thanks for help